# How to get week wise data based on UTC date time in mongodb aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have used mongoose nodejs to get the week wise data. I have data stored in UTC format, the sample data will be like below

```
Steps: {
     "quantity": 25,
     "duration": 100,
     "endTime": "2023-05-18 01:25:53 +0000",
     "startTime": "2023-05-18 01:25:52 +0000"
},
leadId: 10
```

From the set of data I am trying to get the week wise data while user pass timezone as IST, I need to get the data. For example, if user request data from 01-05-2023 to 31-05-2023 I need to query based on startTime from 30-04-2023 18:30:00 to 30-05-2023 18:29:59 (IST is +05:30).

I am trying achieve with following aggregate query

```
activities.aggregate([ { '$match': { Steps: { '$ne': null }, 'Steps.startTime': { '$gte': 2023-04-30T18:30:00.000Z, '$lt': 2023-05-30T18:30:00.000Z }, leadId: 36 } }, { '$group': { _id: { startTime: '$Steps.startTime', endTime: '$Steps.endTime' }, doc: { '$last': '$$ROOT' } } }, { '$group': { _id: { '$dateTrunc': { date: '$doc.Steps.startTime', unit: 'week', timezone: '+05:30', startOfWeek: 'sunday' } }, docs: { '$addToSet': '$doc' } } }, { '$unwind': '$docs' }, { '$project': { _id: '$_id', quantity: { '$toDouble': { '$ifNull': [ '$docs.Steps.quantity', 0 ] } }, duration: { '$toDouble': { '$ifNull': [ '$docs.Steps.duration', 0 ] } } } }, { '$group': { _id: '$_id', quantity: { '$sum': '$quantity' }, duration: { '$sum': '$duration' } } }, { '$sort': { _id: 1 } }, { '$addFields': { startDate: 2023-04-30T18:30:00.000Z, endDate: 2023-05-30T18:30:00.000Z, step: 604800000, bounds: 'full' } }, { '$addFields': { rangeStart: { '$dateToParts': { date: '$startDate', timezone: '+00:00' } }, rangeEnd: { '$dateToParts': { date: '$endDate', timezone: '+00:00' } } } }, { '$addFields': { range: { '$range': [ 0, { '$ceil': { '$divide': [ { '$subtract': [ { '$multiply': [Array] }, { '$add': [Array] } ] }, 12 ] } }, 1 ] } } }], {})
```

Here I am expecting query to run for current week from 27-05-2023 18:30:00 to 03-05-2023 18:29:59. But query is running for the current week from 28-05-2023 00:00:00 to 03-05-2023 11:59:59. Not converted datetime inside week range, it took data basis only. But I am expecting this to run based on date time with data conversion.

Expected output

````
  {
    "duration": 0,
    "quantity": 0,
    "startTime": ISODate("2023-03-25T18:30:00Z"),
    "week": 1
  },
  {
    "duration": 0,
    "quantity": 0,
    "startTime": ISODate("2023-04-01T18:30:00Z"),
    "week": 2
  },
  {
    "duration": 0,
    "quantity": 0,
    "startTime": ISODate("2023-04-08T18:30:00Z"),
    "week": 3
  },
  {
    "duration": 100,
    "quantity": 25,
    "startTime": ISODate("2023-04-15T18:30:00Z"),
    "week": 4
  },
  {
    "duration": 0,
    "quantity": 0,
    "startTime": ISODate("2023-04-22T18:30:00Z"),
    "week": 5
  },
  {
    "duration": 0,
    "quantity": 0,
    "startTime": ISODate("2023-04-29T18:30:00Z"),
    "week": 6
  },
  {
    "duration": 100,
    "quantity": 25,
    "startTime": ISODate("2023-05-06T18:30:00Z"),
    "week": 7
  },
  {
    "duration": 200,
    "quantity": 50,
    "startTime": ISODate("2023-05-13T18:30:00Z"),
    "week": 8
  },
  {
    "duration": 100,
    "quantity": 25,
    "startTime": ISODate("2023-05-20T18:30:00Z"),
    "week": 9
  },
  {
    "duration": 0,
    "quantity": 0,
    "startTime": ISODate("2023-05-27T18:30:00Z"),
    "week": 10
  },
  {
    "duration": 0,
    "quantity": 0,
    "startTime": ISODate("2023-06-03T18:30:00Z"),
    "week": 11
  }
]```
````

Comment: Please provide desired output, otherwise it is really hard to understand your requirements.

Comment: updated expected output

Comment: Then you only need to add `week: "$$weeks"`, see my update

Comment: last two weeks data are not appearing in the link that you shared

Comment: I think you got the basic idea of the query. Adapting the dare ranges should not be too difficult

Answer (score 0):

You should **never** store date values as stings, it's design flaw. Store always proper `Date` objects.

With `Date` values, the `$match` could be simply

```
   {
      $match: {
         "Steps.startTime": {
            $gte: ISODate("2023-05-01T00:00:00+05:30"),
            $lt: ISODate("2023-05-31T00:00:00+05:30")
         },
         leadId: 38047
      }
   }
```

You can group directly by week:

```
   {
      $group: {
         _id: {
            $dateTrunc: {
               date: "$Steps.startTime",
               unit: "week",
               timezone: "+05:30",
               startOfWeek: "monday"
            }
         },
         quantity: { '$sum': '$Steps.quantity' },
         duration: { '$sum': '$Steps.duration' }
      }
   }
```

And to fill missing values with 0, I would suggest `$densify` and `$fill`

```
   {
      $densify: {
         field: "Steps.startTime",
         range: { step: 1, unit: "week", bounds: "full" }
      }
   },
   { $fill: { output: { quantity: 0, duration: 0 } } },
```

With only one input document and without expected result, it is a bit difficult for me to provide the full aggregation pipeline. There would be too many options.

**Update**

Based on the information you provided, I can just guess. `$densify` was introduced in MongoDB version 5.3. If you don't have this version, then you have to write more code. This one may work:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $match: {
         "Steps.startTime": {
            $gte: ISODate("2023-04-01T00:00:00+05:30"),
            $lt: ISODate("2023-05-31T00:00:00+05:30")
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: {
            $dateTrunc: {
               date: "$Steps.startTime",
               unit: "week",
               timezone: "+05:30",
               startOfWeek: "sunday"
            }
         },
         quantity: { '$sum': '$Steps.quantity' },
         duration: { '$sum': '$Steps.duration' }
      }
   },
   { $set: { _id: "$$REMOVE", startTime: "$_id" } },
   { $group: { _id: null, doc: { $push: '$$ROOT' } } },
   {
      $set: {
         doc: {
            $map: {
               input: {
                  $range: [0, {
                     $add: [{
                        $dateDiff: {
                           startDate: ISODate("2023-04-01T00:00:00+05:30"),
                           endDate: ISODate("2023-05-31T00:00:00+05:30"),
                           unit: "week",
                           timezone: "+05:30",
                           startOfWeek: "sunday"
                        }
                     }, 1]
                  }]
               },
               as: "weeks",
               in: {
                  $let: {
                     vars: {
                        week: {
                           $dateAdd: {
                              startDate: {
                                 $dateTrunc: {
                                    date: ISODate("2023-04-01T00:00:00+05:30"),
                                    unit: "week",
                                    timezone: "+05:30",
                                    startOfWeek: "sunday"
                                 }
                              },
                              unit: "week",
                              amount: "$$weeks",
                              timezone: "+05:30"
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     in: {
                        $ifNull: [
                           { $mergeObjects: [
                           {
                              $first: {
                                 $filter: {
                                    input: "$doc",
                                    cond: { $eq: ["$$this.startTime", "$$week"] }
                                 }
                              }
                           }, {week: "$$weeks"}]},
                           {
                              startTime: "$$week",
                              week: "$$weeks",
                              quantity: 0,
                              duration: 0
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $unwind: '$doc' },
   { $replaceWith: "$doc" }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DscB1hOaJcO)

Comment: densify is not working for me

Comment: tried with range as mentioned above but not working

Comment: edited question now, I have used range but got output empty array

Comment: Thanks Wern. I run the query and noticed only till ISODate("2023-05-20T18:30:00Z") data appearing, but according to query end will be 2023-06-03 since we provided end date as 2023-05-31. correct me if I am wrong

Comment: You need to add one week in `$range`, see my update. Or use `{ $dateDiff: { startDate: { $dateTrunc: { unit: "week", date: ISODate("2023-04-01T00:00:00+05:30") ...` instead of `{ $dateDiff: { startDate: ISODate("2023-04-01T00:00:00+05:30")`

Comment: working after adding 1 in $range
```$range: [
              0,
              {
                $add: [
                  {
                    $dateDiff: {
                      startDate: ISODate("2023-04-01T00:00:00+05:30"),
                      endDate: ISODate("2023-06-03T00:00:00+05:30"),
                      unit: "week",
                      timezone: "+05:30",
                      startOfWeek: "sunday"
                    }
                  },
                  1// Add an additional week
                  
                ]
              }
            ]```

Comment: Yes, that's what I did in my last update...